# ZF2 - Multi navigation with navigation

Tags: zend-framework2

Is it possible to have 2 differents navigation ?

For example :

```
//in module.config.php
'service_manager'=>array(
        'factories'=>array(
            'navigation1'=>'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'navigation2'=>'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'navigation'=>array(
        'navigation1'=>array(
            'home'=>array('type' => 'mvc','route' => 'home','active'=>false,'label' => 'Home','title' => 'Home',
                'pages'=>array(
                    'contact'=>array('type' => 'mvc','route'=>'contact','active'=>false,'label'=>'Contact','title' =>'Contact'),
                )
            ),
        ),
        'navigation2'=>array(
            'home'=>array('type'=>'mvc','route'=>'home','active'=>false,'label'=>'Home','title'=>'Home',
            'contact'=>array('type'=>'mvc','route'=>'faq','active'=>false,'label'=>'Faq','title'=>'Faq'),
            ),
        ),

//Dans laout
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('navigation1')->setMinDepth(0);?>
<hr />
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu('navigation2')->setMinDepth(0);?>
```

I would like 2 differents menu with differents pages but this method doesn't run.

Every one has an idea please ?

Thanks

Birzat

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide a custom factory class for each navigation group.  For example, see how ZfcAdmin does this:

1. Create a custom factory class

   ```
   <?php
   namespace ZfcAdmin\Navigation\Service;

   use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

   class AdminNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
   {
       protected function getName()
       {
           return 'admin';
       }
   }
   ```

   Source: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin/blob/master/src/ZfcAdmin/Navigation/Service/AdminNavigationFactory.php
2. Register AdminNavigationFactory

   ```
   // in Module.php
   public function getServiceConfig()
   {
       return array(
           'factories' => array(
               'admin_navigation' => 'ZfcAdmin\Navigation\Service\AdminNavigationFactory',
           ),
       );
    }
   ```

   Source: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin/blob/master/Module.php#L90
3. Define Navigation trees in your module's configuration under the key you specified in the `getName` method of your factory.  As an example, this is how ZfcUserAdmin adds itself to the ZfcAdmin menu:

   ```
   'navigation' => array(
       'admin' => array(
           'zfcuseradmin' => array(
               'label' => 'Users',
               'route' => 'zfcadmin/zfcuseradmin/list',
               'pages' => array(
                   'create' => array(
                       'label' => 'New User',
                       'route' => 'admin/create',
                   ),                        
               ),
           ),
       ),
   ),
   ```

   Source: https://github.com/Danielss89/ZfcUserAdmin/blob/master/config/module.config.php

Answer (score 4):

**/vendor/MyNamespace/library/MyNamespace/Navigation/Service/SecondaryNavigationFactory.php**

```
namespace MyNamespace\Navigation\Service;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class SecondaryNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory {

    protected function getName() {
        return 'secondary';
    }

}
```

**/config/autoload/global.php**

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'secondary' => 'MyNamespace\Navigation\Service\SecondaryNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Item-1.1',
                'route' => 'foo',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Item-1.2',
                'route' => 'bar',
            ),
        ),
        'secondary' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Item-2',
                'route' => 'baz',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
<?php echo $this->navigation('secondary')->menu(); ?>
```